# Fortran 77 and passing an array to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine, fortran77

I have the following code :

```
parameter (maxprt=25)
dimension pt(maxprt)
impt  = maxprt

call rdprob(delt,denr,denw,ders,des,ecapr,ecapw,ein,erb0,erock,ext,iflim,ifmax,ifseg,ilim,ilpt,impt,iout,irlim,ismax,itstep,maxrk,pt,qexto,qfrac,qin,qnxt,qtot,rockr,rockv,t0,te0,tend,ter0,tstart,vol,xin,xs,ir1)

subroutine rdprob(delt,denr,denw,ders,des,ecapr,ecapw,ein,erb0,erock,ext,iflim,ifmax,ifseg,ilim,ilpt,impt,iout,irlim,ismox,itstep,maxrk,pt(25),qexto,qfrac,qin,qnxt,qtot,rockr,rockv,t0,te0,tend,ter0,tstart,vol,xin,xs,ir1)
```

when i go to compile link i get indicating pt is a problem

```
borehole.for: In program `MAIN__':
borehole.for:111: 
   call rdprob(delt,denr,denw,ders,des,ecapr,ecapw,ein,erb0,erock,ext,iflim,ifmax,ifseg,ilim,ilpt,impt,iout,irlim,ismax,itstep,maxrk,pt
                                                                                                                                     ^
Expression at (^) has incorrect data type or rank for its context
```

any ideas on how to fix this or properly call a subroutine while passing an array

Comment: `pt(25)` in the argument list isn't how one says a dummy argument in the subroutine is an array.  But as what you quote isn't a complete example (see [mcve]) I can't say more.  [Also, given the length of the line, the lack of indentation, etc., that can't be Fortran 77.]

Comment: ok cool there is a line length limit? I scanned this code and ocr ed it then "fixed up" the lines so they would be all in one

Comment: `impt` does not contribute anything to the question. Why did you include it?

Comment: sorry impt is just one of the other parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you declare an array argument:

```
parameter (maxprt=25)
dimension pt(maxprt)

call test(pt)
```

and somewhere else

```
subroutine test(a)
dimension a(25)

end subroutine
```